# OData service in Cordova

Tags: cordova, cross-domain, odata, sapui5

I have an SAPUI5 application which is packaged as Cordova application. However, I'm unable to call an OData service from my application. Access origin is already set by default so no change is made there. Is there any other configuration which we need to do to access cross-site OData Service in Cordova?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked .. Problems were :
1. Had to use IPaddress ( like 192.12.121.22:8000/..../service.svc) rather than hostname, as it was internal server.
2. Had to hard code username and password where I declared my odata model.